# Respaldo de SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaria saber como puedo sacar un Backup de mi base de datos, solo necesito las tablas, vistas,procedimientos almacenados,logins y usuarios

> En que opcion de SQL Server puedo sacar eso?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Necesitas solo la estructura o también los datos?

Comment: solo estructura  @LuisCazares

Comment: necesitas un backup o generar el script sql de la creacion de esos objetos, son cosas diferentes.

Comment: la segunda @ronpy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para generar los scripts de esos objetos, desde el SSMS le das click derecho sobre la BD, tareas, generar scripts.. y marcas las que necesites como ves en esta imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo que necesitas es un backup, click derecho sobre la BD, tareas, Generar copia de seguridad... y eliges donde guardarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]